# Arranging and merging Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok, this is more of a question in many parts of the code than a specific one. I am not getting this right.

Let´s say I have 2 Dataframes:

```
**DF1   = Orders**
Ordes N    Customer    Product  Color  Date of delivery   Qty   Amount
A12        John        INJ12      Blue   10/10/2018         5      100,00
A12        John        INJ13      Green  10/10/2018         10     200,00
A13        Francis     COB01      Brown  01/08/2018         2      50,00
A14        Mike        ACE05      Blue   08/08/2018         20     80,00


**DF2   = Inventory**
Orders     Product    Color   Qty
A12        INJ13      Green   5
A12        INJ13      Green   3
A12        INJ12      Gray    5
A14        ACE05      Blue    20
```

What I want to do is to mach orders with inventory withe the orders and get something like:

```
Ordes N    Customer  Date of delivery   Product    Color  Inv Qty   OrderQty   
A12        john      10/10/2018         INJ13      Green  8         10
                                        INJ12      Blue   0         5
                                        INJ12      Gray   5         0
A13        Francis   01/08/2018         COB01      Brown  0         2
A14        Mike      08/08/2018         ACE05      Blue   20        20
```

What I am doing is:
**STEP 1**

```
DF2[reference] = DF2[Order N] + DF2[Product] + DF2[Color]
**DF2.GROUPBY([reference,Order N,Product,Color])[Qty].sum()**
```

This second line of code is giving me duplicate values. I don´t know why.

**Step 2**

```
DF1[reference] = DF2[Order N] + DF2[Product] + DF2[Color]

    **DF2.GROUPBY([reference,Order N,Product,Color])[Qty].sum()**
```

**Step 3**

```
df1_2 = pd.merge(left = DF1,right = DF2,right_on='reference',left_on
='reference')
```

And now I am getting so many strange values that I can´t go on.

Anyone could help me with that?

Comment: In step 3, you can't use "+" in dataframe naming as in df1+2, do df1_2 or something instead.

Comment: Ok, but even df1_2 does not make the results right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `groupby` df2 `sum` the Qty together firstly

```
df2.groupby(['Orders','Product','Color']).Qty.sum()
s=pd.concat([df1.set_index(['OrdesN','Product','Color']),df2],1)
s[['Customer','Dateofdelivery']]=s[['Customer','Dateofdelivery']].ffill()
s=s.fillna(0)
s
Out[145]: 
                Customer Dateofdelivery   Qty  Amount   Qty
A12 INJ12 Blue      John     10/10/2018   5.0  100,00   0.0
          Gray      John     10/10/2018   0.0       0   5.0
    INJ13 Green     John     10/10/2018  10.0  200,00   8.0
A13 COB01 Brown  Francis     01/08/2018   2.0   50,00   0.0
A14 ACE05 Blue      Mike     08/08/2018  20.0   80,00  20.0
```